# using html tags within ruby on rails if statement

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement

i have a method in my application controller that checks whether a user is in the correct group to access certain functions.

My problem is that when a user edits their own account settings i dont want them to be able to edit their group, unless they are part of the transport group. Currently i have this

```
 <%= if logged_in_as_transport? %>
   <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :user_type %><br />
   <%= f.select :user_type, [['Transport','1'],['Staff','2']] %>
   </div>  
 <% end %>
```

My method works fine as it is used to check the permissions on the page. It would be ideal if the drop down box was not visible for other groups but just being disabled would work too.

the above code creates a SyntaxError "unexpected tRPAREN"

```
');@output_buffer.append= ( if logged_in_as_transport? );@output_buffer.safe_concat('
```

if anyone can help that would be great.

Comment: Post the exact error you get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<%= if logged_in_as_transport? %>
```

should be

```
<% if logged_in_as_transport? %>
```

an `if` statement's conditional doesn't have a return value to output to your view's HTML (which is what your'e saying you want to have happen by using `<%=` instead of `<%`)